# Pythonで複数フォルダを1つのZIPファイルに圧縮する方法

Tags: python

Desktop上に、test_dir1というフォルダと、test_dir2というフォルダがあって
これら2つのフォルダを、Pythonを使ってzip_testという1つのフォルダにzip圧縮して入れたいのですが、どうすれば良いですか？

shutilというライブラリを使ってやろうと思ったのですが、1つのフォルダしか圧縮する方法しか見つかりませんでした。

```
import shutil
shutil.make_archive('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/zip_test', 'zip', root_dir='C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/test_dir1')
```

フォルダを別途作成して、そのフォルダ内に2つのフォルダをコピーした後に圧縮したりするのが良いのでしょうか？
もし、1つのコマンドで実行できる方法があるなら、知りたいです。

Comment: 参考: shutil に拘らなければいくつか方法はありそうです。英語版での類似質問 (と回答) - [Python zip multiple directories into one zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46229764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[shutils.make_archive() のソースコード](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/shutil.py#L940) を参考にすると(というよりコピペですが)、以下の様に書けます。

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZIP_DEFLATED

def make_zipfile_from_multiple_directory(zip_filename, src_dirs):
  save_cwd = os.getcwd()
  with ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    for base_dir in src_dirs:
      path_dir, path_base = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(base_dir))
      os.chdir(path_dir)
      zf.write(path_base, path_base)
      for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path_base):
        for name in sorted(dirnames):
          path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
          zf.write(path, path)
        for name in filenames:
          path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
          if os.path.isfile(path):
            zf.write(path, path)

  os.chdir(save_cwd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  root_dir = 'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/'
  zip_filename = os.path.join(root_dir, 'zip_test.zip')
  src_dirs = [os.path.join(root_dir, d) for d in ('test_dir1', 'test_dir2')]

  make_zipfile_from_multiple_directory(zip_filename, src_dirs)
```

Answer (score 3):

`shutil`だと, 二度実行すると zipが置き換えられるし, 一度に複数ディレクトリー指定というのもなさそうです。

とりあえずひとつ分のディレクトリーで `shutil`で作成し, もう一つ分のディレクトリーを `zipfile` で追加するとか, 最初からすべて `zipfile`で行うかになるでしょう

以下は `zipfile`使ったコードです (Ubuntuにて動作)

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile,ZIP_DEFLATED
from pathlib import Path

desktop = Path.home()/ 'Desktop/'
with ZipFile(desktop/'newzip.zip', 'w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    for f in desktop.glob('test_dir*/*'):
        if f.is_file():
            zf.write(f, arcname=f.relative_to(desktop))
```

---

たぶん Desktop辺りでプラットフォームで異なることもあるかもだけど大抵はそのまま動くはず